# How to prevent usercontrol form handling keyboard input (arrow keys) in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, keyboard

my usercontrol contains other controls that can be selected, i would like to implement way of navigating over child controls with arrow keys

The problem is that parent controll intercepts arrow keys and use it to scroll its view what is the thing i want to avoid. I want to solve navigating over contents of control by myself.

How i can take control over standard behaviour that is caused by arrow keys?

Thanks in advance
MTH

Comment: Either forward the keypress or set some property on the hosting panel to ignore events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normally done by overriding IsInputKey() method to tell that you want these keys.  That however won't work for a UserControl, it never gets the focus so the OnKeyDown method never runs.  Instead, override the ProcessCmdKey() method, it is called before the form sees the keystroke.  Like this:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        switch (keyData) {
            case Keys.Left: MessageBox.Show("Left!"); break;
            case Keys.Right: MessageBox.Show("Right!"); break;
            default: return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
        return true;  // used
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override OnKeyDown in your user control, but that doesn't work for arrow keys because they are not 'input keys' (they are navigation keys).

To change the behaviour, override IsInputKey() to tell the system you want to get events for arrow keys:

```
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        bool result = false;

        Keys key = keyData & Keys.KeyCode;

        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Left:
                result = true;
                break;

            default:
                result = base.IsInputKey(keyData);
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: See answer by Hans Passant - that will work as well. IsInputKey works fine in UserControls though (just tested the sample above)

Comment: both answers solve the problem nonetheless use of override on ProcessCmdKey seem to be more right, anyway THANKS!