# Disable certain keyboard actions in TextBoxes. (VC# Windows Form Application)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keyboard

I'm making a game with `TextBox`es but they can cheat if they use `ctrl + a` or `ctrl + z`. How do I make those actions enabled within my textBoxes?

I tried doing this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
    {
        if (x is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)x).KeyDown += textBox_KeyDown;
        }
    }          
}

static void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Z && e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true; 
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't notice the keydown, keyup and keypress events?

Comment: But how do I do it for ctrl plus another key?

Comment: This might be hepful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177201/how-to-prevent-usercontrol-form-handling-keyboard-input-arrow-keys-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

`KeyDown` event occurs when a key is first pressed. Instead, Use `KeyPress` event which occurs when a control has focus and the user presses and releases a key. `KeyPress` event has `KeyPressEventArgs`. SO you will have to use `e.handled = true` instead of `e.SuppressKeyPress` event.

> For using `Keyboard` class and `Key` enum, you have to add `PresentationCore` and `WindowsBase` assemblies to your project references.

**`KeyPress` event:**

```
static void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Z))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I trust this helps you with your problem.